# How can I create a fallback for iframes using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm loading iframes with user-submitted URLs. If the URL cannot load, I want to create a fallback message using Javascript. I already used PHP to ensure that the URL is available.

Comment: If you ensure the url is available then it should always load... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your code?

I'm thinking of using

```
var iframe = getElementById("iframeidhere")
setTimout(chk(),300)
function chk() {
if (!iframe.onload) {
iframe.innerHTML = "what you want to show if it fails"
}}
```

Comment: There are some typos with your code. I'm looking for an event or callback rather than using a timer.
The code is "<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>"